# Horizontal alignment of nodes (with straight line edge connectors)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, forest

What I want is to have three nodes horizontally aligned (the root 1SA, the 1st level child "0--7 HL" and the second level child "Various distributions4") and having straight line connectors with the same y-coordinate so that they look like a single straight line.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning, shapes, trees}
\RequirePackage[edges]{forest}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}   
\begin{forest}  
for tree={rounded corners,
grow'=0, l=0, l sep=2em, 
         child anchor=west, anchor=west,  
          parent anchor=east, 
          tier/.pgfmath=level(),
         shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, align=left, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20, minimum width = 2mm, minimum height = 4mm,
          edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor)|-(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
          }
[{1SA}, calign=child,  calign child=2
        [{0--7 HL}
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions1}}\\Stayman Takis} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions2}}\\Texas} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions3}}\\Stayman normal, if a single major\\Texas, otherwise} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions4}}\\Pass, with bad suit\\Texas, otherwise} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions5}}\\Pass, 0--4 HL\\Texas M 5--7 HL} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions6}}\\Pass, 0--4 HL\\Texas M 5--7 HL} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions7}}\\Pass} ]
        ] 
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the horizontal alignment, one needs to specify `calign=child` for the second level as well. In the code below I simply set it for the entire tree.

Actually, the code sets `calign=child edge`. This yields the desired result even when `child/parent anchor` differs from `anchor`. (`calign=child` aligns  `anchor`s, while `calign=child edge` aligns `parent anchor` and `child anchor`.)

I have also included the automatic computatation of the middle child: `calign child=(n_children()+1)/2`. (Maybe having `calign=mid-child` and `calign=mid-child edge` is not a bad idea?)

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning, shapes, trees}
\RequirePackage[edges]{forest}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}   
\begin{forest}  
for tree={rounded corners,
grow'=0, l=0, l sep=2em, 
         child anchor=west, anchor=west,  
         parent anchor=east, 
         tier/.pgfmath=level(),
         shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, align=left, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20, minimum width = 2mm, minimum height = 4mm,
         edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor)|-(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
         calign=child edge, calign child=(n_children()+1)/2,
          }
[{1SA}, 
        [{0--7 HL}, 
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions1}}\\Stayman Takis} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions2}}\\Texas} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions3}}\\Stayman normal, if a single major\\Texas, otherwise} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions4}}\\Pass, with bad suit\\Texas, otherwise} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions5}}\\Pass, 0--4 HL\\Texas M 5--7 HL} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions6}}\\Pass, 0--4 HL\\Texas M 5--7 HL} ]
            [{\underline{\textbf{Various distributions7}}\\Pass} ]
        ] 
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! I've ported that code back to the source and it seems to work well.  In doing my MWE I somehow lost the right edge out of "0--7 HL".  The node shouldn't abut the vertical line joining the children. How should I restore that edge?

Comment: So what I need to do is \forestset{
nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles, calign=child edge, calign child=(n_children()+1)/2,},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
},
}

Comment: pgfmath? I mean, it defaults that way?

Comment: I need to use the above forestset and change to "0-7 HL, nice empty nodes" to get the effect I want.